# Need to intersect 2 dictionaries by key and value in c#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have 2 structures:

```
public struct Customer
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
}

public class OrganizationDto
{
    public int OrgId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PeopleCount { get; set; }
    public string CCEmail { get; set; }
    public string address { get; set; }
}
```

And 2 dictionaries:

```
Dictionary<string, Customer> dataCustomer = new Dictionary<string, Customer>();
Dictionary<string, OrganizationDto> dataOrganization = new Dictionary<string, OrganizationDto>();
```

How can I map the 2 by:
key and different address. So I need the items that have the same key but with diffrerent address.
I tried:

```
Dictionary<string, OrganizationDto> changed = dataOrganization
            .Where(item => dataCustomer .Keys.Contains(item.Key))
            .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);
```

This gives me the intersection by key, but I don;t know how to select only the ones with the different address(and common key of course).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

compare Address properties when filtering

```
var changed = dataOrganization
        .Where(item => dataCustomer.Keys.Contains(item.Key) 
                       && item.Address != dataCustomer[item.Key].Address)
        .ToDictionary(item => item.Key, item => item.Value);
```